# Spring Security 5.1.5 with WebFlux user disable not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I am trying to implement a Web Application using Spring WebFlux Framework and MongoDB. Everything is working as expected, but even though the **enabled** property is set to **false** in the database, It's still allowing me to log in successfully. Which should not be the case. My Security Config is as below -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class WebfluxSecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Constants constants;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository users) {
         return (username) -> users.findByUsername(username)
                    .map(u -> new UserAuth(u.getUserId()
                            , u.getUsername()
                            , u.getPassword()
                            , u.isEnabled()
                            , !u.isAccountExpired()
                            , !u.isCredentialsExpired()
                            , !u.isAccountLocked()
                            , UserAuth.getGrantedAuthorities(u.getRoles().toArray(new String[0]))
                            , StringUtils.isEmpty(u.getAuthSalt()) ? u.getUsername() : u.getAuthSalt()
                        )
                    );
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain3(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
         http
          .authorizeExchange()
              .pathMatchers("/web/**").authenticated()
              .pathMatchers("/**").permitAll()
          .and().formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
          .and().logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout");

         return http.build();
    }
}
```

User entry in mongodb is -

```
{
    "_id": "5d149e3b3c1206008cf56af9",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "{noop}admin",
    "firstName": "Admin",
    "lastName": "1",
    "email": "admin@eightfolds.in",
    "enabled": false,
    "accountLocked": true,
    "roles": ["ADMIN"]
}
```

Can anyone please help me to understand what I am doing wrong.

Still not able to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reporting this.
Your configuration has nothing wrong with it. The behaviour of checking whether a user account is disabled is not yet part of WebFlux.
I have created an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7113) on the spring-security GitHub repo to add this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I guess in that case we have nothing to do other than waiting still the bug is fixed by spring team. Can you please suggest me any stop gap solution for now.

Comment: @Krishnendu which version of spring-security are you on?

Comment: I believe it's Spring security 5.1.5 as I am using spring-boot-starter-security 2.1.6

Comment: @Krishnendu If you want to try out spring-security 5.2.0.M3, then you can use the new method `setPostAuthenticationChecks` on `UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager` and set the enabled check yourself.

Comment: If you stay on 5.1.5, you can create a custom `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` that extends `UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager` and override the `authenticate` method to include the checks for enabled.

Comment: Ok I will try the last approach